# vb.net class read-only property as list(of T)

Tags: vb.net, list, class, properties, readonly

I am looking for an example of the usage of a `read-only property as list(of T)`

```
Public ReadOnly Property oList As List(Of String)
Get
    Return ...
End Get
```

When I normally use list(of T) I always use the `New` constructor in front of my variable type `Public Property oList as New list(of T)`

But when I do this now I get an error message from Visual Studio.
So how does this work?

I have never used an read-only property before..

Comment: Initialize the private backing field var in the class constructor.  Alternatively, you can check it for Nothing before returning it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
Private myList As New List(Of String)

Public ReadOnly Property List As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return myList
    End Get
End Property
```

or, using an automatic initialized readonly property (supported in Visual Studio 2015, i.e. VB14 and above):

```
Public ReadOnly Property List As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
```

Now consumers can add and remove from your list:

```
myObject.List.Add(...)
myObject.List.Remove(...)
```

but they cannot replace the list as a whole:

```
myObject.List = someOtherList ' compile error
myObject.List = Nothing       ' compile error
```

This has has a few advantages:

- The invariant that `List` is never `Nothing` is always ensured.
- The consumer of your class cannot do counter-intuitive stuff like "connecting" the lists of two objects:

  ```
  myObject1.List = myObject2.List   ' Both objects reference the same list now
  ```

---

As a side note, I would recommend to expose an *interface* (`IList`) in such a situation instead of the concrete class:

```
Public ReadOnly Property List As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)
```

This gives you all of the features mentioned above. In addition, you can later change the concrete type of your list to, for example, `MyFancyListWithAdditionalMethods` without breaking the contract, i.e., without having to recompile the consumers of your library.